# I2C_Anything ++

Tags: arduino-uno

a request for information has been formulated, how to say it?

in Ascii: i2C dialog: Tx -----> Rx ----> PCF8574

a drawing
https://nsm09.casimages.com/img/2023/02/28/23022802163423870818122937.jpg

3 elements on the i2C bus

- an Arduino "Tx" to read values from an electric counter
- an Arduino "Rx" to recycle the values and also to dialogue on a Rs485 bus
- and a PCF8574 which receives the commands from the Arduino "Rx" to operate telestage relays

1st question:

```
I2C_writeAnything (foo1); 
(foo2);
(foo3);
I2C_writeAnything (foo X?);
```

What is the maximum number of foo1 .. foo2 ...foo10 that I can put ?

Is this the right method?
or do we have to group them by pack?

2nd question:

when we use several libraries, in their sketch we find calls to #include <Wire.h>
that are added to the main sketch.
Can this be a cause of problems?

thanks

```
Arduino "Tx" for electrical measurements (simulation with a "random") 

void loop()  {

unsigned long foo1 = random(2294967295);  
unsigned long foo2 = random(2294967295);
unsigned long foo3 = random(2294967295);
unsigned long foo4 = random(2294967295);
unsigned long foo5 = random(2294967295);

if (timer0.available()) { 
Wire.beginTransmission (SLAVE_ADDRESS);
 
I2C_writeAnything (foo1);
I2C_writeAnything (foo2);
I2C_writeAnything (foo3);
I2C_writeAnything (foo4);
I2C_writeAnything (foo5);
       
Wire.endTransmission ();
   
if (!Wire.endTransmission ()) { Serial.println ("endTransmission () : "); }
timer0.restart();
} 
} /*Loop*/  




//Arduino "Rx" for reading and using the Electrical values 
#include <Wire.h>
#include <I2C_Anything.h>           //http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c
const byte MY_ADDRESS = 42;
  
volatile boolean haveData = false;
volatile unsigned long foo1; 
volatile unsigned long foo2;
volatile unsigned long foo3;
volatile unsigned long foo4;
         
#include "PCF8574.h"                //https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/PCF8574
PCF8574 PCF27a (0x3D);  // adjust addresses i2c pcf8574

//...setup
//...loop

void receiveEvent (int howMany)  {


// if (howMany >=  4) 
if (howMany >=  (sizeof foo1))    {
I2C_readAnything (foo1);  
I2C_readAnything (foo2); 
I2C_readAnything (foo3);
I2C_readAnything (foo4); 

haveData = true;  
}  
}  // end of receiveEvent
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with limit? The limit for data transferred in a single transaction is the size of the buffer in the Wire library. And the second question is not readable. Please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking

Comment: yes I have modified my text
thanks Chris

Comment: `Can this be a cause of problems?` ... you did not say anything about problems

Comment: Including libraries wil only generate problems if there is an incompatability with something in the rest of your code. Did you see any problems? Why do you think this might be a problem? You need to include Wire, since you are using it for the I2C communication.

Comment: Please format your code properly, especially repair the indentation.

Comment: The test assembly works, but after an hour or two the communication remains frozen.
A reset on the Arduino and it starts again.
I made a test by adding in the setup this line :

Wire.setWireTimeout(3000,true);

https://www.fpaynter.com/2020/07/i2c-hangup-bug-cured-miracle-of-miracles-film-at-11/

and my assembly works well, no more blocking.

I just have to find how to manage my data by 32bytes packets.

Answer (score 0):

A return on the module of Electrical measurements.
with an i2C bus.
(it can be useful for other people)

No more errors, no more blocking, it purrs like a kitten.

For the structure I copied the work of Peter_n (thanks to you)
it helped me a lot:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/i2c-not-sending-all-data-with-i2c_anything/293609

and for the :  Wire.setWireTimeout(3000,true);
not sure where to put it, it's put on both parts.

a copy of the sketches

Master_I2C_Anything_Linky_uneStructure_bigOctes.ino

```
  // base Written by Nick Gammon - May 2012 : 
// struct de Peter_n : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/i2c-not-sending-all-data-with-i2c_anything/293609

//------------------ Dialogue on i2c bus between 2 ATMega328 - Arduino-Uno ------------
// --- 2x6 32-bit values  ou 1x 7 
//------------------   functional test model ---------------------------
// Add in setup :  Wire.setWireTimeout(3000,true); 

  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <I2C_Anything.h>   //http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c

  const byte SLAVE_ADDRESS = 42;

  #include "Timers.h"         //https://github.com/nettigo/Timers
  Timer timer0;   // delay 

//------------  struct -------------------------  
//------------ linky info ---- 7 types de variables --------//
 
  struct sensorData_STRUCT {
  byte sensorNumber;
    uint16_t A;   // uint16_t PAPP in VA 
    uint32_t B;   // uint32_t BASE index in Wh 
    uint32_t C;   // uint32_t HCHC index heures creuses en Wh 
    uint32_t D;   // uint32_t HCHP Index heures pleines en Wh 
    uint8_t E;    // uint8_t  IINST  Returns in Amp 
    uint8_t F;    // uint8_t ISOUSC  Returns ISOUSC 
    uint8_t G;    // uint8_t PTEC Periode tarifaire en cours (0 = HP, 1 = HC)
     uint8_t H;    // test
  } sensorData[1]; // [x] number of structures

//---------------------- SETUP --------------------
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println(F(" Master_I2C_Anything_Linky_structure_double.ino "));
  Serial.print(__DATE__); Serial.println(__FILE__);
  
  Wire.begin ();  

  Wire.setWireTimeout(3000,true); 
  
  // fill fixed data
  sensorData[0].sensorNumber = 0;
 // sensorData[1].sensorNumber = 1; //desactivé

  timer0.begin(SECS(3));  //delay transmission   

  } /*Setup*/

//-------------------- LOOP -----------------------
  void loop()  {
      
//---------------- strucuture ------------
// collect new data
  sensorData[0].A = 10 ; 
  sensorData[0].B = random(2000000000);
  sensorData[0].C = random(2000000000);
  sensorData[0].D =  random(2000000000) ;      
  sensorData[0].E =  random(2000000000) ;
  sensorData[0].F =  random(2000000000) ; // valeur fixe
  sensorData[0].G = 70 ; // valeur fixe
  //     = 19 octes
//unsigned long : non-negative integer of  0 à 4 294 967 295 sur 32 bits de 4 octets
   
//------------------       
         
  if (timer0.available()) { 

 // 1; 2; choix du nbr de structre
  for( int sensor = 0; sensor < 1; sensor++)  {
    // transmit the data
    Wire.beginTransmission( SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    I2C_writeAnything( sensorData[sensor]);
       
    int error = Wire.endTransmission (); //(true) ?
     if( error != 0) {
      Serial.println(F("Error, no acknowledge from Slave"));
    }
  }

    timer0.restart();
  }
  
  } /*Loop*/  

//---------------------- End pgm ----------------------------
```

Slave_I2C_Anything_PCF8574_4DO_uneStructure_bigOctes.ino

```
/*
 *  DESCRIPTION :    
 *  un Arduino Uno en liaison avec un module i2c PCF8574 avec 4 Relais
 *  il recoi aussi d'un autre Arduino des valeurs en Kw pour le basculement des relay
 *   
 *    
 *  LIBRAIRIES:
 *    - Rob Tillaart pour PCF8574 https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/PCF8574
 *    - Nick Gammon  for bus i2c  http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c
 *    - Timers de Łukasz Tretyn   https://github.com/nettigo/Timers
 *    
 *  ELEMENTS: sur le bus i2c
 *    - Expander PCF8574 avec module Metasys JC / 4DO - 0X3D  i2c adress
 *    - ATMega328  pour mesure Electrique
 *    - ATMega328  en Reception 
 *         
 *  MODIFICATION:  
 *    -x- model de Peter_n : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/i2c-not-sending-all-data-with-i2c_anything/293609/11
 *    -o- 
 *    -o-
 * 
 *     RAS 
*/

//------ Mars 2023 -------- Linky PCF8574 - 4DO / Bus i2c -----------------//

// -------------  Functional TEST BUS I2C -----------------------//
// une struct de 19 Octes, pour un maximum  de 32octes

   
//------ i2C Bus ------------
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <I2C_Anything.h>
  const byte MY_ADDRESS = 42;
  
  // The struct must be the same in the Master and in the Slave
  //unsigned long:4 octet (32 bits) - max 4294967295
  struct sensorData_STRUCT {
  byte sensorNumber;
    uint16_t A;   // uint16_t PAPP in VA 
    uint32_t B;   // uint32_t BASE index in Wh 
    uint32_t C;   // uint32_t HCHC index heures creuses en Wh 
    uint32_t D;   // uint32_t HCHP Index heures pleines en Wh 
    uint8_t E;    // uint8_t  IINST  Returns in Amp 
    uint8_t F;    // uint8_t ISOUSC  Returns ISOUSC 
    uint8_t G;    // uint8_t PTEC Periode tarifaire en cours (0 = HP, 1 = HC)
     uint8_t H;    //
    };

/*  struct sensor2Data_STRUCT {
  byte sensor2Number;
    int G;
    int H;
    int I;
    int J;
    int K;
    int L;
    }; */

    
  // A special struct for the received sensor data
  volatile sensorData_STRUCT sensorDataNew;
  
  // A flag to indicate new data
  volatile boolean haveData = false;

  // The normal sensor data
  sensorData_STRUCT sensorData[1];  //nbr de structure [2]
   
          
//---------------- PCF8574 -------------------------------
  #include "PCF8574.h"
  PCF8574 PCF27a (0x3D);  // adjust addresses i2c pcf8574

  #define RELAY_ON  0    //  
  #define RELAY_OFF 1    // 

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//      -----------------          SETUP          --------------------- 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() {

  Wire.begin (MY_ADDRESS);  // bus i2C
  Wire.onReceive (receiveEvent);

  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println(F(" SlaveI2CAnythingPCF8574Structure_bigOctes "));
  Serial.print(__DATE__); Serial.println(__FILE__);
  
  // fill fixed data
  sensorData[0].sensorNumber = 0; 

  Wire.setWireTimeout(3000,true); 

  PCF27a.begin();           // i2C PCF8574
  
//--------- testing IsConnected i2c PCfx ------------
  Serial.print(F(" PCF8574_LIB_VERSION : \t")); Serial.println(PCF8574_LIB_VERSION);
  if (!PCF27a.begin())   {
    Serial.println(F("could not initialize..."));
    }
  if (!PCF27a.isConnected())   {
    Serial.println(F("=> not connected"));
  }
  else   {
    Serial.println(F("=> connected!!"));
    }  
         
  } /* fin Setup */
  
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//         -----------------        LOOP      ------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 void loop() {
 
//---------------- i2C bus -------------------------------
  int sensor;  int sensor2;
  
    if( haveData)  {
    // New data has arrived, copy it in one of the two sensorData.
    // Disable interrups as short as possible
    // The interrupts are disabled to avoid an receiveEvent interrupt that writes new data.
    noInterrupts();
    sensor = sensorDataNew.sensorNumber;


  if( sensor == 0 || sensor == 1) {         // destination, source, size
  memcpy( &sensorData[sensor], (const void *) &sensorDataNew, sizeof( sensorData_STRUCT));

  }
  haveData = false;
  interrupts();
    
    printData(sensor) ; //print Data
    cmdRelay() ;        // Relay PCF8574
   }
   
 } /* fin Loop */

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   -------------------  Receiving messages I2C    ------------------ 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//howMany est le nombre d'octets reçus et par conséquent combien vous pouvez lire
//avec Wire.read(), pour un maximum de 32 octes.

 void receiveEvent( int howMany) {
  if( howMany == sizeof( sensorData_STRUCT)) {
    I2C_readAnything( sensorDataNew); 
         haveData = true;
  }
  else {
    // something is wrong. Wrong number of bytes received.
    // it is possible to set a volatile variable to an error.
  }
 }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   -------------------  Relay Control   ------------------ 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 void cmdRelay() {
//-------- Relay 1 ---------  
  if (sensorData[0].A > 829308135 ) { PCF27a.write(0, RELAY_ON); }
  else { PCF27a.write(0, RELAY_OFF); }
     //Serial.println(PCF27a.read(0));
//-------- Relay 2 ---------  
  if (sensorData[0].B > 304929158) { PCF27a.write(1, RELAY_ON); }
  else { PCF27a.write(1, RELAY_OFF); }
      //Serial.println(PCF27a.read(1));
//-------- Relay 3 ---------  
  if (sensorData[0].C > 590793899 ) { PCF27a.write(2, RELAY_ON); }
  else { PCF27a.write(2, RELAY_OFF); }
     //Serial.println(PCF27a.read(2));
//-------- Relay 4 ---------  
  if (sensorData[0].D > 304929158) { PCF27a.write(3, RELAY_ON); }
  else { PCF27a.write(3, RELAY_OFF); }
      //Serial.println(PCF27a.read(3));
 }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   -------------------  Print data   ------------------ 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void printData(int sensor) {

  if (sensor == 0 ) {
    Serial.print(F( "------ sensor["));
    Serial.print( sensor); Serial.println(F( "] ------"));
    Serial.print(F( "a PAPP  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].A);
    Serial.print(F( "b BASE  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].B);
    Serial.print(F( "c HCHC  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].C);
    Serial.print(F( "d HCHP  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].D);
    Serial.print(F( "e IINST = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].E);
    Serial.print(F( "f ISOUSC= ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].F);
    Serial.print(F( "g PTEC  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].G);
     Serial.print(F( "h test  = ")); Serial.println( sensorData[0].G);

Serial.println(sizeof( sensorData_STRUCT));
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
//------------------------------ End pgm -------------------------------------
```